# How do i merge multiple .png images as a single image using java?

Tags: java, image, servlets

I want to send multiple .png images as an single image through servlet `response.getOutputStream().write(encoder.pngEncode());`
But i can send only one image at a time,but i need to send multiple images through response object using java.  If anyone knows please give me your inputs.

```
   // Create a set of charts
   JFreeChart chart1=null;

   BufferedImage buf[] = new BufferedImage[5]; 
   PngEncoder encoder[] = new PngEncoder[5]; 
   for (int i=0; i<5; i++ ) 
   {            
       buf[i] = chart[i].createBufferedImage(400, 350, null); 
       encoder[i] = new PngEncoder( buf[i], false, 0, 9 ); 
       System.out.println("i= "+i); 
       resp.getOutputStream().write( encoder[i].pngEncode() );           
   }
```

Comment: What do you want to do this for? What is the expected end result?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to send multiple images through a single response?

While possible by using a multi-part MIME response, **this is highly unusual and rarely implemented as the client needs to know how to interpret it.**  If your client is just some an arbitrary web browser, this approach won't work.  If your client is your own applet/software, then maybe.

Another option might be to send a single image that is built up from other images, but that would depend very much on your use case.

Comment: currently i am doing monitor screen for my application,in this i need to display multiple jfree charts in a single jsp using servlet response.right now i am displaying one chart at a time ,but i am having five charts three timeserious chart and two bar chart.
but in pie chart it is possible becoz predefined api is there ,but in rest of the charts how do i send in a single image ,please explain with code sample.

Comment: *"plzsendtehcodes"*? Haha. I don't have any. You are going to have to do some research and experimentation. I repeat: this is unusual, and your client must support it. You have not defined your client, so I cannot tell if this idea even has a chance of working. Are you sending this to a browser? And what is wrong with separate requests?

Comment: ya,browser only,in jsp page onclick of submit based on the input param i need to display all the jfree chart results,right now i am using dropdown list for each and every chart need to display,so based on the chart number i am displaying particular chart from the JFreeChart api in my servlet class,i have done 5 type of charts and i am having .png byte array also,but i can send one by one at a time ,but my requirement is onclick of submit i need to display all the charts in a single page,i am not using struts,it is simple jsp and servlet.

Comment: OK.  Either *A)* have HTML show 5 separate images (and 5 requests).  Or *B)* combine the 5 images into a single image--one on top each other.